# How to get Json data to html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Alright guys, I'm fairly new to Json, so sorry if this doesn't make alot of sense..

I'm trying to retrieve data from a json file to display in a html document using jQuery. I've been able to console.log the raw json data with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.getJSON("http://mtgjson.com/json/AllSets.json",    function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Wich gives me the following data.

[image]

I'm trying to make an `<ul>` and put all the data 'name' into the `<li>` using jQuery. So I end up with a huge list of names. I've been searching for the past 3 hours and haven't found anything that can help me. So any help would be appreciated greatly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend reading http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp to further understand how to access JSON properties

Comment: Thank you, I will definitly get into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.getJSON("http://mtgjson.com/json/AllSets.json",    function (data) {

        var ul = $('<ul />');

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            ul.append(  $('<li />', {text: value.name})  );
        });

        $('body').append(ul);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DYfn8/1/)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. I'll dig into the 'each', 'key' and 'value' attributes and see if I can get some more info on this subject. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A point to start could be this:

```
$.getJSON("http://mtgjson.com/json/AllSets.json",    function (data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    console.log(key, value);
  });
});
```